# Find $\sup_{x\in(0,\alpha)} \frac{n x^2}{x^3+n^3}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Find
$$\sup_{x\in(0,\alpha)} \frac{n x^2}{x^3+n^3}$$
where $\alpha>0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$.

I found $\sup$ doing the derivative. Is there an alternative way (without derivative)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prove only the case when $\alpha\geq {2}^{1/3}n$.
For $\alpha<2^{1/3}n$ smaller values of the supremum may be proved.

We can use Young's inequality
$$|ab|\leq \frac{|a|^p}{p}+\frac{|b|^q}{q}$$
with 
$$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$$
The equality holds when $|a|^p=|b|^q$.

A direct application of the above inequality with 
$$a=2^{2/9}n\\ b=\frac{x^2}{2^{2/9}}$$
and $p=3, q=3/2$ will yield
$$nx^2\leq \frac{2^{2/3}n^3}{3}+\frac{2|x|^3}{2^{1/3}3}=\frac{2^{2/3}}{3}(|x|^3+n^3)$$
i.e.
$$\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}=\frac{2^{2/3}}{3}$$
which is attainable when
$$2^{2/3}n^3=\frac{|x|^3}{2^{1/3}}$$
i.e. when $x=2^{1/3}n$.